# Generate random number using numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to use `round(random.uniform(1.5, 1.9),2)` to generate random number and also use `numpy.random.random((5,10))` to generate a list includes 5 elements and every element has 10 items.
Can I do them simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `numpy.random.uniform()` and `numpy.round()`:

```
numpy.round(numpy.random.uniform(low=1.5, high=1.9, size=(5, 10)), decimals=2)
```

Comment: Thank you but I want a random number between 1.5 and 1.9 ( I mean between two specific numbers)

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Please don't forget to  [mark an answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)